# Multiple recyclerviews in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have a list of questions loaded using a recyclerview and each question have multiple answers, do i need to create a second recyclerview to load the answers or there is a better way to accomplish that.

this my code :

`

```
  package com.raje3.raje3.Ask;

  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.raje3.raje3.Browse.browseData;
  import com.raje3.raje3.R;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;



 public class AskRecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AskRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder>  {

private List<AskBrowseData> list = new ArrayList<>();

public AskRecyclerAdapter(List<AskBrowseData> list) {

    this.list = list;

}


@Override
public AskRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.browse_questions_item, parent, false);
    return new AskRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AskRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.q_text.setText(list.get(position).getQ_text());
    holder.q_date.setText(list.get(position).getQ_date());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}



public static class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView q_text, q_date;

    public viewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        q_text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.q_text);
        q_date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.q_date);

    }
}

}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create dynamic view,
instead of having recylerView
use scrollview as parent and add question and answer dynamically.